# Content of .xml files

Tags: xml

I have 50 .xml files (for example) in one folder, but only two of them contain the word "Kravic". Can I use Total Commander (or Windows cmd console) to get the name of files that contain the word "Kravic"?

Thanks

Comment: Use from Cmd >DIR *Kravic*.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do in Total Commander.

- Search for: ***.xml**
- Find text: **Kravic**

[image]